# Flutter unable to request for permissions with permission_handler library

Tags: android, flutter, dart

## Information

1. I am testing this on both Android and Linux. The problem appears in both.
2. I have done the relevant setup according to the page in pub dev. By modifying my `grade.properties` and `android/app/build.gradle`

## The problem

As the title says the library doesn't work. This is the block of code that I have that requests permissions.

```dart
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class Perms {
  void requestPermissions() async {
    if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
      print("Granted.");
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code sample shown on the [page](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) for the library on pub dev. This is the error I get when it hits this block of code. The complete code is linked [here](https://paste.rs/zQY)

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method checkPermissionStatus on channel flutter.baseflow.com/permissions/methods)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:165:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannelPermissionHandler.checkPermissionStatus (package:permission_handler_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_permission_handler.dart:16:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      Perms.requestPermissions (package:passync/perms.dart:5:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

This is my `AndroidManifest.xml` file. This is the manifest file located in the main folder. There are other manifest files in debug and profile. I'm not sure if I need to add the same permissions to them too.

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.passync">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

   <application
        android:label="passync"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

## What I have tried

1. Create a new project and duplicate the code. Ended up with the same error.
2. Ran `flutter clean` as suggested in many SO answers. Still failed.
3. Request other permissions to see if it's a storage-specific thing. I get the same error even when asking for different permissions.

Tell me if there's any missing information, and I'll edit the post. Thanks.

Comment: are you run flutter upgrade?

Comment: What's your flutter version? Have you checked if it's a device issue?

Comment: Did you add `AndroidX` to `gradle.properties`?

Comment: @lepsch No, I'll find out how to do that.

Comment: @JunsuCho Yes I have

Comment: @ZonilyJame ```Flutter 3.0.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 85684f9300 (2 weeks ago) • 2022-06-30 13:22:47 -0700
Engine • revision 6ba2af10bb
Tools • Dart 2.17.5 • DevTools 2.12.2
```

Answer (score 1):

As the time of this writing [`permission_handler`](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) plugin is only available for `Android`, `iOS`, and `Windows`. It's going to fail with `MissingPluginException` on every other platform.

Also, `permission_handler` has a set-up to be followed for both `Android` and `iOS`. Please read the instructions from [the official docs](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler#setup). Below is a copy-paste from the docs:

### Android

###### AndroidX

As of version 3.1.0 the permission_handler plugin switched to the AndroidX version of the Android Support Libraries. This means you need to make sure your Android project is also upgraded to support AndroidX. Detailed instructions can be found [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/android/androidx-migration).

The TL;DR version is:

1. Add the following to your `gradle.properties` file:

   ```
   android.useAndroidX=true
   android.enableJetifier=true
   ```
2. Make sure you set the `compileSdkVersion` in your `android/app/build.gradle` file to `33`:

   ```
   android {
     compileSdkVersion 33
     ...
   }
   ```
3. Make sure you replace all the Android dependencies to their AndroidX counterparts (a full list can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)).

Add permissions to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. There's a `debug`, `main`, and `profile` version which are chosen depending on how you start your app. In general, it's sufficient to add permission only to the `main` version. [Here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler/example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) is an example `AndroidManifest.xml` with a complete list of all possible permissions.

### iOS

Add permission to your `Info.plist` file. [Here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler/example/ios/Runner/Info.plist) is an example `Info.plist` with a complete list of all possible permissions.

> IMPORTANT: This is because the `permission_handler` plugin touches all different SDKs and because the static code analyser (run by Apple upon App submission) detects this and will assert if it cannot find a matching permission option in the `Info.plist`. More information about this can be found [here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/26).

The `permission_handler` plugin uses [macros](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler/ios/Classes/PermissionHandlerEnums.h) to control whether permission is enabled.

You must list permission you want to use in your application:

1. Add the following to your `Podfile` file:

   ```
   post_install do |installer|
     installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
       ... # Here are some configurations automatically generated by flutter

       # Start of the permission_handler configuration
       target.build_configurations.each do |config|

         # You can enable the permissions needed here. For example to enable camera
         # permission, just remove the `#` character in front so it looks like this:
         #
         # ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
         # 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1'
         #
         #  Preprocessor definitions can be found in: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler_apple/ios/Classes/PermissionHandlerEnums.h
         config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
           '$(inherited)',

           ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
           # 'PERMISSION_EVENTS=1',

           ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
           # 'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=1',

           ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
           # 'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=1',

           ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
           # 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',

           ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
           # 'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',

           ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
           # 'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=1',

           ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
           # 'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',

           ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
           # 'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',

           ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
           # 'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',

           ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
           # 'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=1',

           ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
           # 'PERMISSION_SENSORS=1',   

           ## dart: PermissionGroup.bluetooth
           # 'PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH=1',

           ## dart: PermissionGroup.appTrackingTransparency
           # 'PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY=1',

           ## dart: PermissionGroup.criticalAlerts
           # 'PERMISSION_CRITICAL_ALERTS=1'
         ]

       end 
       # End of the permission_handler configuration
     end
   end
   ```
2. Remove the `#` character in front of the permission you do want to use. For example, if you need access to the calendar make sure the code looks like this:

   ```
    ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
    'PERMISSION_EVENTS=1',
   ```
3. Delete the corresponding permission description in `Info.plist` e.g. when you don't need camera permission, just delete 'NSCameraUsageDescription' The following lists the relationship between Permission and `The key of Info.plist`:

   | Permission | Info.plist | Macro |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | PermissionGroup.calendar | NSCalendarsUsageDescription | PERMISSION_EVENTS |
   | PermissionGroup.reminders | NSRemindersUsageDescription | PERMISSION_REMINDERS |
   | PermissionGroup.contacts | NSContactsUsageDescription | PERMISSION_CONTACTS |
   | PermissionGroup.camera | NSCameraUsageDescription | PERMISSION_CAMERA |
   | PermissionGroup.microphone | NSMicrophoneUsageDescription | PERMISSION_MICROPHONE |
   | PermissionGroup.speech | NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription | PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER |
   | PermissionGroup.photos | NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription | PERMISSION_PHOTOS |
   | PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse | NSLocationUsageDescription, NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription, NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription | PERMISSION_LOCATION |
   | PermissionGroup.notification | PermissionGroupNotification | PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS |
   | PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary | NSAppleMusicUsageDescription, kTCCServiceMediaLibrary | PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY |
   | PermissionGroup.sensors | NSMotionUsageDescription | PERMISSION_SENSORS |
   | PermissionGroup.bluetooth | NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription, NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription | PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH |
   | PermissionGroup.appTrackingTransparency | NSUserTrackingUsageDescription | PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY |
   | PermissionGroup.criticalAlerts | PermissionGroupCriticalAlerts | PERMISSION_CRITICAL_ALERTS |
4. Clean & Rebuild

Comment: I made the changes to my `gradle.properties` as well as to `android/app/build.gradle`. But the problem still persists.

Comment: What's the platform you're testing? `iOS`, `Android`, `macOS`, `Windows`, `Linux`, or `Web`?

Comment: I'm testing on Android and Linux. The issues are present in both.

Comment: Well, there is no implementation for `Linux` for this plugin as it only supports `Android`, `iOS` and `Windows`. Now, is the error on Android part exactly the same?

Comment: Did not realize there was no implementation for Linux. Ran it again on Android and oddly enough it works now.

Comment: @lepsch i also facing same issue also i tried all the above steps and clean 7 times